# How can I save file in QTabwidget?

Tags: python-3.x, save, pyqt5, qtabwidget

That's my code, but I have to add save method to save text in the tab. How can I do it?

```
class Main(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Main, self).__init__(parent)

        self.initUi()

    def initUi(self):
        self.setWindowTitle("Text Editor")
        self.resize(800, 600)

        self.tab = QTabWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.tab)
        self.tab.tabCloseRequested[int].connect(self.on_tab_close)

    def addtab(self, content, fileName):
        self.tab.addTab(QPlainTextEdit(str(content)), str(fileName))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just keep a reference to each new editor you create, instead of adding the instance directly.

```
class Main(QMainWindow):
    # ...
    def initUi(self):
        self.setWindowTitle("Text Editor")
        self.resize(800, 600)

        self.tab = QTabWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.tab)
        self.tab.tabCloseRequested[int].connect(self.on_tab_close)

        self.editors = []

    def addtab(self, content, fileName):
        editor = QPlainTextEdit(str(content))
        self.tab.addTab(editor, str(fileName))
        self.editors.append(editor)

    def save(self):
        index = self.tab.currentIndex()
        if index < 0:
            return
        fileName, filter = QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(self, 'Save')
        if fileName:
            with open(fileName, 'w') as f:
                f.write(self.editors[index].toPlainText())
```